# Aurelia Multi-page App?

Tags: url-routing, aurelia

If I have main.ts file setup like so...

**Main.ts**

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework'
import environment from './environment';

//Configure Bluebird Promises.
(<any>Promise).config({
  warnings: {
    wForgottenReturn: false
  }
});

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources');

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }



  // PLAYING AROUND - Log to Console the Value of ShowLanding Session Storage
  let showLanding = false;
  console.log(showLanding);
  // let showLanding = sessionStorage.getItem("show_landing");

  if (showLanding || showLanding === null) {
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('landing'));
  } else {
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('blog/blog'));
  }
}
```

I have a "Landing.html/.ts" file in the root of my app, and this bit of code seems to work well. Meaning, if "showLanding = false" the app will load to my "blog.html" page, and if it's true, it will load to my "Landing.html" page.

What I'm trying to do is create an Admin page. Anytime URL is visited "....com/admin" take me to "admin.html" page I have setup.

Is that possible to do front-end? Only other way I know would be to match URL and static-serve from server route, yeah?

Comment: To be clear, are you really needing to have different roots? Couldn't you just use the built in router? See the Hub documentation: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/

Comment: Check out the section on Push State details here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/1 This will allow you to have foo.com/admin instead of foo.com/#/admin

Comment: That's what I have configured, but not working. Docs say I need "server side configuration" but it does not elaborate and I'm not sure what would need to be done there. I would think whether push state is on/off if I go to .../#/admin or .../admin either way it should navigate to that page, but my admin page just goes wherever the router-view is. How do I get it to just navigate to the admin view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working (the way I wanted it to work) by just simply reading window.location.pathname and setting my admin page as app root.

```
so my Main.ts was changed to:

  ...

  if (showLanding || showLanding === null) {
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('landing'));
  } else if (window.location.pathname == "/admin") { 
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('admin/admin'));
  } else {
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('blog/blog'));
  }
}
```

I'm sure this probably isn't the *best* way to accomplish this, but it seems to be working for now. I'll be sure and update this if there are any issues I run into.

Also, if someone else wants to chime in with any alternative thoughts, concerns, suggestions, or feedback, please do! Thanks!

Comment: This was very simple and very useful. I would preferably set root per route, but this will work for now.